# a.s. for all $t$ or for all $t$ a.s.?

Tags: probability-theory, terminology, article-writing

Assume that we have some equality,
$$
X (t) = Y(t). \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)
$$

I imagine that if I say "(1) holds a.s. for all $t>0$" it means that 
$$
P\{X (t) = Y(t) \text{ for all } t>0 \} = 1, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (2)
$$ 
whereas if I say "(1) holds for all $t>0$ a.s." it means that for all 
$$
 \forall t >0: P\{X (t) = Y(t) \} = 1. \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (3)
$$

Is my interpretation correct? Also, are there ways to distinguish between (2) and (3) unambiguously?

**Addition**. The question also concerns relations.

Consider some relation, for exapmle
$$
X (t) \in A. \quad  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1')
$$

Does "(1') holds a.s. for all $t>0$" mean 
$$
P\{X (t) \in A \text{ for all } t>0 \} = 1, \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (2')
$$ 
and does "(1') holds for all $t>0$ a.s." mean
$$
 \forall t >0: P\{X (t) \in A \} = 1? \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (3')
$$

Comment: Two processes are said to be _indistinguishable_ if (2) holds, whereas they're said to be _modifications_ if (3) holds. Note that (2) implies (3) and that (3) does not imply (2) in general. However, if their sample paths are right-continuous then (3) implies (2).

Comment: I would say your interpretation is accurate regarding what you added.

Comment: I would see it the other way round as in the question. "(1) holds for all $t>0$" is (supposedly) a measurable subset and this can have probability one; in formulas I'd express that as Sinusx's formula (2). Nevertheless, there is possibility for ambiguity, so **always** try to explain clearly which of the two cases you mean.